# switching to another custom view

Tags: xcode, cocoa, custom-view

i am just new to objective-c programming.  now, i am creating a cocoa game application.

like many game apps, the game that i created has multiple views. i have already prepared the custom view, and now my problem is changing the view when i click a button... like in my main menu, i have options like play, instructions and high score. when the player clicks instructions button, the view should switch to the instructions view that i created...

can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put all of the views into an [NSTabView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/), and just switch the tab. (The “tabs” don't have to have visible tabs. You can have a tabless tab view.)

Harder, but easier to animate, is to manipulate the view hierarchy. Take what was the current view out of its superview, and add what will be the current view as the new subview.* The core methods for this are in [NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/); the simplest way to animate these transitions is to talk to the views' [`animator` proxies](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimatablePropertyContainer_protocol/).

More relevant documentation:

- [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/)
- [Tab Views guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TabView/)
- [Animation Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/Animation_Overview/) (especially “[Cocoa Animation Proxies](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/Animation_Overview/MacOSXAnimTech/MacOSXAnimTech.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004952-CH6-SW9)” et seq.; you may want to stick to something simpler than Core Animation for now)

*Don't forget to retain *all* of the game-mode views just after loading the window, so they don't die on you when you take each one out of the superview.